# How do I add scroll onto this div?

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, positioning, css-position

The div that I need to have the ability to scroll is the : I need it to scroll in side the timeholder div and preferrably have a custom scrollbar but that is not necessary. I have tried plug ins and css solutions but to no avail. I am preferably looking for a solution in jquery...

```
    <div class="timeHolder">
        <div class="timeView">              
<!-- Year Markers -->            
                <div class="yearMarker">1943</div><div class="yearMarker">1944</div><div class="yearMarker">1945</div><div class="yearMarker">1946</div><div class="yearMarker">1947</div><div class="yearMarker">1948</div><div class="yearMarker">1949</div><div class="yearMarker">1950</div><div class="yearMarker">1951</div><div class="yearMarker">1952</div><div class="yearMarker">1953</div><div class="yearMarker">1954</div><div class="yearMarker">1955</div><div class="yearMarker">1956</div><div class="yearMarker">1957</div><div class="yearMarker">1958</div><div class="yearMarker">1959</div><div class="yearMarker">1960</div><div class="yearMarker">1961</div><div class="yearMarker">1962</div><div class="yearMarker">1963</div><div class="yearMarker">1964</div><div class="yearMarker">1965</div><div class="yearMarker">1966</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1969</div><div class="yearMarker">1970</div><div class="yearMarker">1971</div><div class="yearMarker">1972</div><div class="yearMarker">1973</div><div class="yearMarker">1974</div><div class="yearMarker">1975</div><div class="yearMarker">1976</div><div class="yearMarker">1977</div><div class="yearMarker">1978</div><div class="yearMarker">1979</div><div class="yearMarker">1980</div><div class="yearMarker">1981</div><div class="yearMarker">1982</div><div class="yearMarker">1983</div><div class="yearMarker">1984</div><div class="yearMarker">1985</div><div class="yearMarker">1986</div><div class="yearMarker">1987</div><div class="yearMarker">1988</div><div class="yearMarker">1989</div><div class="yearMarker">1990</div><div class="yearMarker">1991</div><div class="yearMarker">1992</div><div class="yearMarker">1993</div><div class="yearMarker">1994</div><div class="yearMarker">1995</div><div class="yearMarker">1996</div><div class="yearMarker">1997</div><div class="yearMarker">1998</div><div class="yearMarker">1999</div><div class="yearMarker">2000</div><div class="yearMarker">2001</div><div class="yearMarker">2002</div><div class="yearMarker">2003</div><div class="yearMarker">2004</div><div class="yearMarker">2005</div><div class="yearMarker">2006</div><div class="yearMarker">2007</div><div class="yearMarker">2008</div><div class="yearMarker">2009</div><div class="yearMarker">2010</div><div class="yearMarker">2011</div><div class="yearMarker">2012</div><div class="yearMarker">2013</div><div class="yearMarker">2014</div><div class="yearMarker">2015</div><div class="yearMarker">2016</div><div class="yearMarker">2017</div><div class="yearMarker">2018</div><div class="yearMarker">2019</div>

<!-- End Year Markers -->           

        </div>
    </div>    

</aside>
```

The CSS:

```
/*---------- Start Timeline 2 ---------*/

.timeContainer { position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 90%; margin: 2% 0% 5% 0%; top: 0px; right: 30px; overflow:hidden;}

 .timeHolder { position: absolute; width: 100px; margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;}

.timeView { position:absolute; width: 100px; height: 28105px; max-height: 28105px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-image:url(../img/longTimeBG3.png); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position: top left; z-index: 90;; 
}



/*---------- End Timeline 2 ---------*/
```

--------------------------EDIT ADD ANOTHER ISSUE IN ----------------------------

Ok I have this doc ready animation that moves the timeView div up to the year 2011 (or -24820 px up)

Now the scroll position is now set at the top at the year 2011 and will not scroll up any more

here is the script the init the animation:

```
$('.timeView').animate({         
        easing: 'easeInExpo',
        top: '-=24820px',
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the bare minimum that's required for this problem? I suspect a lot of this code isn't at all needed... and possibly a JSFiddle.

Comment: You should try making a reduced exemple on http://jsfiddle.net to help us help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GSzZw/32/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
position : absolute;
```

is conflicting with the scroll... Do you really need it to be absolute? Try setting

```
position : relative
```

to your inner div as in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GSzZw/27/ The key is to have your timeView height bigger than your timeHolder height (Both height have to be set) and add

```
overflow-y : scroll;
```

or

```
overflow-y : auto;
```

----- EDIT ------
You will **NOT** be able to scroll up if you change the "top" value.

If you want to **scroll** to a specific place use jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and take a look at this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/GSzZw/48/

To animate use :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".timeHolder").animate({         
        scrollTop: '24800',
     }, 10000);
});
```

instead of :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".timeHolder").scrollTop(24800);
});
```

​
​

Hope that helps.

Comment: OK left this little tidbit out but check out my edit to the main problem, Great solution but here comes the real problem...

Comment: Ok I get your other problem, but I think you should post a new question for your other problem. Please add fiddle for us to help you out.

Comment: I edited my answer to complete your new question. If you need more help with scrolling animations please post a **new question**

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to animate it in the fashion I was attempting?

Comment: OK everything works great one little odd thing though... If you scroll all the way to the top, the scroll stops at where your mouse pointer is. It will only scroll back down if you roll over the div. I set max height on all the classes but it still does it

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Scrollable is the best and esiest solution.

http://jquerytools.org/download/

Other solution is ScrollTo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your css

```
overflow: auto;
```

on your div you want to have the scrollbar.

Comment: you have to specify an height to your timeHolder maybe ?